# React Native Component not working check render method of App

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, redux

i'm using **React Native** for building an **Android App**

I'm trying to import a **component** in **index.android.js** file from the folder located in **app/containers/AppContainer.js**.

When i run the code i got thi error:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`**

this is my **index.android.js** file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {  createStore,Provider, applyMiddleware, combineReduxers, compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';


import {  AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { expect,assert } from 'chai';

import reducer from './app/reducers';
import AppContainer from './app/containers/AppContainer'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({ predicate: (getState,action) => __DEV__ });

function configureStore (initialState) {
 const enhancer = compose(
      applyMiddleware(
         thunkMiddleware,
         loggerMiddleware,
      ),
     );
  return createStore(reducer, initialState, enhancer);
 }

const store = configureStore({});



const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Appetizing', () => App);
```

and this is my **AppContainer.js** file:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import ReactNative from 'react-native'
 const {
   View,
   Text,
 } = ReactNative

class AppContainer extends Component{

render(){
  return <View>
    <Text style={{marginTop: 20}}>
    I am app container
    </Text>
  </View>
  } 

 } 


export default AppContainer
```

Comment: Have you tried `import {AppContainer} from './app/containers/AppContainer'` ?

Comment: @G0dsquad yes , not works. i got the same error.

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me if I include the component and render it in a standard view e.g. home.js (rather than `index.android.js`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

`import {  createStore,Provider, applyMiddleware, combineReduxers, compose } from 'redux';`

The way named imports work in ES6 is that if the name does not exist, it simply is initialized as `undefined`, and so when trying to render `<Provider>`, react complains.

The `Provider` that you are looking for is inside the [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) package, which you have to install in addition to `redux`. Your code should look like this:

```
import {  createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReduxers, compose } from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following in **AppContainer.js**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import ReactNative from 'react-native'
 const {
   View,
   Text,
 } = ReactNative

export default class AppContainer extends Component{

render(){
  return <View>
    <Text style={{marginTop: 20}}>
    I am app container
    </Text>
  </View>
  } 

 }
```

Comment: thanks, but not solve my problem i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your App to this.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

`import ReactNative from 'react-native'
 const {
   View,
   Text,
 } = ReactNative`

for better undetstanding, you can imagine module `from 'react-native'` like an object with one 'magic' key - **default**

`{
  default: ReactNative
  View: ...
  Text: ...
}`

es6 imports, and in this case - react native bundler, resolves `import ReactNative from 'react-native'` with accessing to `default` property, not whole module

and then you try to access `default.View` which isnt possible, cause ReactNative class dont have it

instead, you should use syntax `import ReactNative, {View, Text} from 'react-native'` if you want to access exported non-default properties of module